# Filtering realm swift objects with calculation needed

Tags: swift3, realm, nspredicate

I have the following object model:

```
    public class Geofence: Object, Mappable {
        @objc public dynamic var id: String?
        @objc public dynamic var name: String?
        @objc public dynamic var uuid: String?
        @objc public dynamic var type: String?
        @objc public dynamic var latitude = 0.0
        @objc public dynamic var longitude = 0.0
        @objc public dynamic var radius = 0
        ...
    }
```

and my requirement is to get **Geofence** objects in range of a specific distance like so:

```
func getGeofences(location: CLLocation, inDistance: Double = 20000.0) -> [Geofence] {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()   
            return realm.objects(Geofence.self).filter("type == 'AREA'").filter({
                location.distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: $0.latitude, longitude: $0.longitude)) + CLLocationDistance($0.radius) <= inDistance
            })
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

However, what this does, is: it only gets the objects with type == 'AREA' and performs the calculation in memory using the swift **standard** filter(_  isInlcuded: (Geofence) throws -> Bool ) rethrows -> [Geofence] function which can be pretty expensive if I get from realm 1.000.000 objects and do the calculation in memory.

What I need instead, is to perform the calculation directly using realm and get from realm only the relevant objects.

Is this possible using realm ? (realm subqueries?)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Realm's `filter` operation uses `NSPredicate`s, which don't support such calculations that you would need. You'll need to figure out a workaround, such as dividing your `Geofence` objects into smaller areas and hence using a predicate that can fetch less objects using existing `NSPredicate` filters, then use Swift's `filter` operation on the smaller amount of objects.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thank you for your response. In the meantime I found this, https://github.com/mhergon/RealmGeoQueries/blob/master/GeoQueries.swift and https://github.com/mhergon/RealmGeoQueries . Would be interesting to know if it does just filtering the actual Results<Object> like I did, or does the actual calculations using realm ?

Comment: Well, why don't you just check the code, since it is open source and you already found it on GitHub. Looking at the code it is clear what is achieved using `NSPredicate`s and hence Realm's `filter` function and what is achieved using `Swift`s built-in `filter`.